# Why does my Set function for my Theme color not work onStart - Powerapps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I am beginning to creat an app on powerapps plattform. I can't find a reason why this Set function for my Color Theme onStart doesn't work since it works for everyone else
Maybe someone knows the reason why?
The issue here is that it wants a value

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srrW0.png)

Comment: Could you edit your question and copy/paste the whole code here?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be formatted correctly, assuming you have a closing }) at the end. Try deleting the comma after gblAppColors and rewriting it.

You may need to save and exit the editor to try to refresh. On first look though, it appears your Set() function is written correctly.

Comment: seems not to work. the Set() wants a value. I dont get it